# jSpinner not displaying the months

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I have placed a spinner on my JFrame (Drag and Drop GUI).
When i click it, i have written this event in it

```
          private void jSpinner1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

          String months[] = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May",
          "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November",
         "December" };
         SpinnerModel model = new SpinnerListModel(months);
         jSpinner1.setModel(model);

         }
```

It doesn't display the months, when i click the spinner.Please give me an idea.May be i am using it for the first time,so making some silly mistake :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I never created custom `SpinnerModel`, because implemented methods in API works for me as I expected,
- use [`SpinnerDateModel`](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/UsingSpinnerDateModeltocreateJSpinner.htm), rest is in the [tutorial about `JSpinner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) including code examples for that.